# Is using more then 1 CDN helpful?

Tags: wordpress, browser, httprequest, cdn

So at moment I am running my personal blog on WordPress using the plugin "W3 Total Cache". I am using Cloudflare and have succesfully changed my DNS settings. Because I am developing the WordPress theme myself I have to think about the css and js being used.

So at the moment I want to include Font Awesome (4) and I was thinking about using a CDN. I found 2 candidates. One using Cloudflare and the other using MaxCDN.

I once read that some (older?) browser's limit there number of simultaneous downloads from the same host. (Not sure if this also include's mobile browser's?)

Does it help to use different CDN's? Or should I not use any CDN stored files (links) at all, because I am using Cloudflare and it should recognize static content? (not sure if there is any truth to the last part?).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic

Comment: May I ask in what way is it off-topic? I am the one asking the question so how is that possible, or does it not comply to any of stack overflow's rules?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions about programming. Where's the programming question?

Comment: Yes, it's not a pure programming question. Did not know that was a requirement. I thought everything related to programming would be okey.

Comment: It would be unfair to call this question off-topic. I feel that this question has a performance aspect to it, hence relevant..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit on the number of requests the browser will send to a domain name at a given time.

Right now the limit is 6-10 requests for the desktop browsers. At the time of IE6, this limit was 2.

This limit is also applicable on mobile browsers.

So, if your website has a lot of content that needs to downloaded in parallel(images?), then it makes sense to use 2 CDNs and have different host names.